# ubuntu 13.04 not working properly after being upgraded from 12.10

Tags: 13.04, upgrade

I have HP Pavillion G6 laptop with dual boot with Ubuntu & windows.

Today I tried to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu 13.04, all the updates files (1501 files in my case) were downloaded successfully, but during the installation of the updates, I lost my internet connection and I found that my laptop had shut down.

When I restarted it, found that many of the applications were upgraded but there is no battery or networking icon on the top panel.

In the network manager it says that networking is not possible with the current version. So I am not even able to connect to the internet. All the applications are not either not working properly or its taking too much time to launch them, so I close them down.

It's also taking too long to restart or shut down and, more times than not, I have to forcibly shut down.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to complete the installation of the downloaded packages, run from a shell this command:

$ sudo apt-get install -f

and possibily report the output of the command (take a picture with your phone if you cannot connect in some way).

Let us know